# How can I output subprocess script to GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, subprocess, output

I'm struggling with converting output into a GUI from within another GUI.
I know there are similar posts but without the knowledge, I can't make heads or tails of them to my problem.

I have a script using os.system to recall information from mdadm --details about my RAID array. I also have a small, simplistic script for a GUI with a subprocess so the button will recall the script. But I cannot get it to output the code to another GUI window.

This is my script for the os.system.

```
import os
os.system("sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0 | grep -A 3 State && grep -A 3 RaidDevice")
```

The other script is my simple GUI I can't tweak to get my desired results.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
top = Tk()

top.title('RAID Status')
top.geometry("250x160")

def raidStat():
   import subprocess
   subprocess.call(['./raidScripts/mdadmRaid.py'])

button1 = Button(top, text = "Check Status", command = raidStat)
button1.grid(row=1,column=0)

top.mainloop()
```

The os.system script works in the terminal and returns results in the text editor.

I can't get anything else to work in terms of output for the GUI because I don't know the code.

Comment: Ok. So that would be something like: import subprocess, then subprocess.run with the same command which should grab the output? Making it more likely to work with the GUI or will it still need some tweaking anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal change for your script to do that:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
top = Tk()

top.title('RAID Status')
top.geometry("250x160")

def raidStat():
   import subprocess
   myproc = subprocess.run(['./raidScripts/mdadmRaid.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   messagebox.showinfo("Result", myproc.stdout)

button1 = Button(top, text = "Check Status", command = raidStat)
button1.grid(row=1,column=0)

top.mainloop()
```

Note that we now redirect `stdout` to `subprocess.PIPE` and use `stdout` attribute of created process object to access its content. Starting with Python 3.7 you can just call `subprocess.run()` with `capture_output=True` instead of dealing with `stdout` (and/or `stderr`).

As is in your code, the script output was not touched and all by Python. That is the reason why you could see it on the console, but could not access it to display it in your GUI.

Comment: I made the changes but I still get the same error messages as before, am I missing some sort of package or key bit of information?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/raidScripts/mdadmStatus.py", line 12, in raidStat
    myproc = subprocess.run(['./raidScripts/mdadmRaid.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 383, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './raidScripts/mdadmRaid.py'

Apologies for the multiple messages.

Comment: But that error indicates the script (`./raidScripts/mdadmRaid.py') is not there. Perhaps the GUI bit is called from some other place (than expected?) I.e. check that and perhaps update the path as needed.

Comment: The other problem unrelated to this that I'd see around the corner is call of sudo in `os.system`. That should prompt you for your user's password in the console anyways, which is likely not what you want calling it from a GUI.

Comment: I've tried other means of reaching the file. For instance, when I'm in the folder where the file is stored, the full path is /home/pi/Desktop/raidScripts. But i've tried it both ways and it makes no difference, can't see the path being a problem. It's all being done on a Raspberry Pi and not as the root user, so the sudo bypasses that and when I tried to call the command without it, it told me I didn't have the permissions, sudo helped.
I'll look into whether or not the button calls from somewhere else, but I'm relatively new to anything code so I'm learning as I go.

Comment: If `errno` is `2` (`No such file or directory`), the path **is** a problem (either not correct, not correct relative to where the execution takes place if relative, or not reachable somewhere in a tree without perms for instance)..

Comment: Did you try using the fullpath of mdadmRaid.py in subprocess.run()?

Comment: Yes I noticed that after I had written it that it meant it would be a problem regardless. The file not being found for whatever reason is actually the only cause of it not working at the minute. 
I added (shell = True) to the end of the subprocess line of code and it allows me to bring up the new GUI window when I click on Check Status, but it doesn't output the information to it.

Now I get the error: 

/bin/sh: 1: ./raidScripts/mdadmRaid.py: not found

Any ideas of how to fix, what is hopefully the last of any issues with this script?

Comment: Try to add `print(os.getcwd())` (of course you need to import `os`) before calling `subprocess.run()`.  Notice that `mdadmRaid.py` is in the same directory of `mdadmStatus.py`, so the result of `os.getcwd()` would be `/home/pi/Desktop/raidScripts`.  Therefore, suggest to change `./raidScripts/mdadmRaid.py` to `mdadmRaid.py`.

Comment: I got it working! I didn't change the path to the os.system script, I just moved the GUI script out of that folder and stuck it on the Desktop, that seemed to do the trick.
It must have been a conflict with both of them being in the same folder.
Thanks acw1668 and you especially Ondrej K, the help is really appreciated.

Comment: Putting the two scripts together is not the cause of your problem.  The problem is that you use a wrong path.  You can get the directory name of your main script using `script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` and then construct the full path of `mdadmRaid.py` using `os.path.join(script_path, 'mdadmRaid.py')`.

Comment: I'll use that the next time the n acw1668. I'm sure it's easy once you get the gist of it but incorporating it into my script just now will confuse me and most likely lead me to break it in some way. 
It works just now so I'll leave it be for the time being. Thanks very much again for the input and advice on the matter.

Comment: Whilst I've got the thread still running, is it possible to adjust the size of the messagebox.showinfo window to suit the result? Maybe to make it more horizontal so that the text has room.
It seems to only have one size, meaning the raid information I've pulled out is bunched up and the lines are crossed over the top of one another, making it a little untidy looking.